# Is there a way for me to wildcard a friend class in C++?

Tags: c++, googletest, friend

I'm using gtest to unit test a cpp class. Consider a situation in which I'd like to make the test class a friend of the actual class, so it can unit test its private state. This works fine for me. The problem is that while using the very helpful `TEST_P` macro which allows you to parameterize test instantiation, the framework mangles the test name a bit.

So I have something like

```
class FooTester {
    FooTester() {}
}

TEST_P(FooTester, TestCoolFeature) {
// test my cool feature that needs access to Foo's internal state
}
```

which is great but to allow this I must provide

```
class Foo {
    friend class FooTester_TestCoolFeature;
}
```

we can see through macro magic gtest creates a new class I haven't explicitly declared which is a combination of the test class and the test method name.

This is ostensibly fine but a bit ugly. It would require me to add a new friend class for each new test method which requires this access. The only real, if unlikely, problem is that if gtest were to change its implementation and mangle the class names differently, it could break my tests.

Is there a way to use some `#define` magic or similar to declare all `FooTester*` classes as `friend`s?

Comment: Tests shouldn't generally rely on private internal state

Comment: No, there's no way to wildcard a friend declaration.  You could do something like `friend class TooTestAccess` and then add static functions to that class that expose what you need.

Comment: You can also befriend a template, and have the different instantiations expose different private/protected members.  While Mooing Duck's point stands, Dependency Inversion (including template policies) - possibly combined with mocking - may also help.

Comment: Agreed I generally wouldn't do it but I've found myself in a situation where my options are to bend that rule, or completely rewrite several hundred broken tests (which I did not originally write, but I digress).

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `friend` classes for that. If you would like to access `Foo` from `FooTester`, inherit it publicly:

```
class FooTester : public Foo
{
    FooTester() {}
}
```